# How can I close a window using Javascript in google Chrome (v38 and above) /firefox (v33 and above)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Following options doesn't work - 
1) window.close();
2) window.open('','_self','');window.close();

Answer (score 0):

`window.close()` should work only if the window is opened by a parent window. If you are trying to open a window directly from your desktop and run the `window.close()`, it will not close the window.